# Overview Of Redis Architecture?

Tags: redis

I'm researching about Redis Architecture. and I don't understand some point about it. please, you explain for me.

1. follow some document says: "Client will only write data to Master Instance and read-only from Slave instances.".  Is it right? if true, in case, Slave is failed, how will read data redis?
2. About process start a Redis instance, how happened it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use [Redis sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) to monitor several redis instances. When the master fails, Sentinels will elect a new master.